# How do I change this query to use a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

I currently have

```
select * from A where A.id not in 
    (select B.id from B where B.user ='b') and A.user <> 'b'
```

How do I change this query to use a `JOIN` -- something like `LEFT JOIN user AS last_replied_user ON topic.last_replied_by = last_replied_user.uid`

Comment: does `user` or `topic` has any relationship with `A or B` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users u
left outer join topic t on u.id=t.last_replied_by
where t.last_replied_by IS NULL
```

This will get you all users where the user id is not found in the last replied by column in the topics table.

Comment: but b.user is not a foreign key for table_A id. In table b, b.topic_id has many user

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing exactly what your tables look like, but the above query should still work. Just replace b.user with the column that contains the user id that would be in the users table (is that last_replied_by?). Edited query to show example.